# SQL Statement take long time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database and having a table containing too many records. Before it was working fine but now when I run SQL Statement takes time to execute.
Sometime cause the SQL Database  to use too much CPU.
This is the Query for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPAnswer1](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AttrID] [int] NULL,
[Kidato] [int] NULL,
[Wav] [int] NULL,
[Was] [int] NULL,
[ShuleID] [int] NULL,
[Mwaka] [int] NULL,
[Swali] [float] NULL,
[Wilaya] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPAnswer1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the following down is the sql stored procedure for the statement.

```
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[uspGetPAnswer1](@ShuleID int, @Mwaka int, @Swali float, @Wilaya int)
as

SELECT ID,
       AttrID,
       Kidato,
       Wav,
       Was,
       ShuleID,
       Mwaka,
       Swali,
       Wilaya
FROM   dbo.tblPAnswer1
WHERE  [ShuleID] = @ShuleID
       AND [Mwaka] = @Mwaka
       AND [Swali] = @Swali
       AND Wilaya = @Wilaya
```

What is wrong in my SQL Statement. Need help.

Comment: Are the columns on which your are putting where clause indexed ?

Comment: Is this a very high transaction database ?

Comment: You're *searching by an exact value* of a `float` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Index on the `ID` column and include `ShuleID`, `Mwaka`, `Swali` and `Wilaya` columns.  That should help improve the speed of the query.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ID_ShuleID_Mwaka_Swali_Wilaya
ON tblPAnswer1 (ID)
INCLUDE (ShuleID, Mwaka, Swali, Wilaya);
```

Comment: The table is already clustered on the ID column, why the NC again? Moreover, it's irrelevant for this particular query.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an index on ShuleID, Mwaka, Swali and Wilaya columns. The order of columns in the index should depend on distribution of data (the columns with most diverse values in it should be the first in the index, and so on).

And if you need it super-fast, also include all the remaining columns used in the query, to have a covering index for this particular query.

EDIT: Probably should move the float col (Swali) from indexed to included columns.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the table? You may need additional indices as you are not using the primary key to query the data. This article by Pinal Dave provides a script to identify missing indices.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/

It provides a good starting point for index optimization.

Comment: My table have more than 10,000,000 records